# Change label to match numeric part from ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="additional_1">Additional #1 :</label>
    <input type="text" id="additional_1" name="pnr_remarks_modify[additional][]">
    <a href="#" class="addInput">New</a> - <a href="#" class="removeInput">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I am adding (cloning) / removing the complete '.row' element with this code:

```
var cloneCntr = 2;
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.addInput', function() {
  // clone the div
  var row = $(".row").last();
  var clone = row.clone();

  // change all id and name values to a new unique value
  $("*", clone).add(clone).each(function() {
    if (this.id) {
      this.id = (this.id).slice(0, -1) + cloneCntr;
    }
    if (this.name) {
      this.name = this.name;
    }
  });
  ++cloneCntr;
  $('#wrapper').append(clone);
});

$('#wrapper').on('click', '.removeInput', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(e.currentTarget);
  target.parent().remove();
})
```

Every time I click on `New` I got a clone from the previous object but changing its ID. For example:

First Click on New

Additional #1 :
        
        New - Remove

Second Click on New

Additional #1 :
        
        New - Remove

But as you can see the `for` attr and the label text remain the same. I need to change them to (on each new clone):

- `for` needs to be the same as the new ID
- label text needs to be Additional # + cloneCntr

But I don't know how to achieve this part, can I get some help?

[Here is](https://jsfiddle.net/9j6n6fb6/13/) the jsFiddle where I am playing around this

Comment: What is the specific problem or question?

Comment: @charlietfl updated the question, let me know if it's more clear now

Comment: So what should text say if I add a few and remove some of them from the top?

Comment: @charlietfl for now, Additional + (latest+1),  for example you add 6 and remove the one on position 3, the next text should said Additional+7, the idea is to reorder the items but I think this is more complex than I have

Comment: You can get the label from the clone and update the _for_ attribute ... `var forControl = $('label', clone).attr('for')` will get the one you just cloned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the rows each time one is added or removed and update based on row index. Use one function that gets called within both event handlers

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.addInput', function() {
  var clone = $(".row").last().clone();
  clone.find('input').val(''); // clear value on clone input
  $('#wrapper').append(clone);
  updateCounts();
});

$('#wrapper').on('click', '.removeInput', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(e.currentTarget);
  target.parent().remove();
  updateCounts();
});


function updateCounts() {
  $('#wrapper .row').each(function(i) {
    var num = i + 1,
      $row = $(this),
      inputId = 'additional_' + num;

    $row.find('label').text('Additional #' + num + ' :').attr('for', inputId);
    $row.find('input').attr('id', inputId)
  });

}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9j6n6fb6/15/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use another function to generate `html` with new `id` and `for` attribute like following.

```
function getRow(index){
    return '<div class="row">' +
                '<label for="additional_'+index+'">Additional #'+index+' :</label>' +
                '<input type="text" id="additional_' + index + '" name="pnr_remarks_modify[additional][]">' +
                '<a href="#" class="addInput">New</a> - <a href="#" class="removeInput">Remove</a>' +
           '</div>';
}

var cloneCntr = 2;
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.addInput', function () {
    var clone = getRow(cloneCntr);

    ++cloneCntr;
    $('#wrapper').append(clone);
});
```

#### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9j6n6fb6/14/)

Comment: Doing this, the structure of the `<div class="row">` will be in both the HTML and in the JS, which is a maintenance _nightmare_. Someone _will_ eventually change one and not the other.  If one is going to use this method then the first, original row on the page should also be created by a call to `getRow()`.